# Spring JPA: PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa, cassandra

I've searched for hours on this issue but cannot find one that matches my situation exactly and has a solution.

I have an existing Cassandra database but intend to migrate to MongoDB in the near future. I'm writing a Spring Rest API with Spring Data JPA to use the Cassandra DB but want to make sure that I can easily switch to Mongo without much pain in the future.

```java
@Entity
@Table("stb") 
public class NetworkDevice {
    @Id
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "deviceid", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String deviceid;
// remaining fields/getters/setters/etc omitted
```

The common NetworkDeviceRepository

```java
public interface NetworkDeviceRepository {
    NetworkDevice findByDeviceid(String deviceid);
}
```

The Cassandra Repository

```java
public interface NetworkDeviceCassandraRepository extends NetworkDeviceRepository, CassandraRepository<NetworkDevice, String>{}
```

The Mongo Repository

```java
public interface NetworkDeviceMongoRepository extends NetworkDeviceRepository, MongoRepository<NetworkDevice, String> {}
```

When the project starts I end up with the following error

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type NetworkDevice!
```

It appears as though Spring is getting confused and looking for `CrudRepository` method names as fields on my `NetworkDevice` object, but that makes absolutely no sense to me and nothing I've tried (for hours) affects the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are you using @Repository nnotation in repository?

Comment: I've tried with that annotation, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Apparently Cassandra was identifying the `NetworkDeviceMongoRepository` as a potential Cassandra repository because it was in the same package as the `NetworkDeviceCassandraRepository`.

Moving these two Repositories to different packages resolved the issue.

**Before**

```
> Repository Package
    + NetworkDeviceRepository.java
    + NetworkDeviceMongoRepository.java
    + NetworkDeviceCassandraRepository.java
```

**After**

```
> Repository Package
    + NetworkDeviceRepository.java
    > Mongo Package
        + NetworkDeviceMongoRepository.java
    > Cassandra Package
        + NetworkDeviceCassandraRepository.java
```